# How to change hashes key in Puppet without using a custom function?

Tags: ruby, puppet, hash

Is it possible in Puppet to change hashes keys without calling a custom functions within a class or custom type?

Pretty much calling regular ruby functions.

```
$myHash.keys.each { |k| $myHash[k + "_toto"] = $myHash[k]; $myHash.delete(k) }
```

Comment: Does Puppet use global variables like that, or is that something you've done?

Comment: @tadman $myHash is actually coming from a parametrized class. It's not a global.

Comment: @Spredzy If it starts with a `$` then it is always a global.